# Check for authentication from View ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, identity

I want to generate the login link or profile link in a view, depending on user authentication state, but nothing happens, and I get an empty place like this: `<div> </div>`

```
<div>
     @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
     {
          Html.ActionLink(GlobalRes.BlogEditProfile, "Edit", "Profile");
     }
     @if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
     {
          Html.ActionLink(GlobalRes.Login, "Login", "Account");
     }
</div>
```

Please tell me where my mistake is?

Answer (score 0):

I found how i can implement this checking, but not from View.

I can check it from a method in controller like this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public PartialViewResult AuthenticationLink()
{
    var item = new MenuLinkItem();
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        item.Text = GlobalRes.BlogEditProfile;
        item.Action = "Edit";
        item.RouteInfo = new { controller = "Profile", area = "Peoples" };
    }
    else
    {
        item.Text = GlobalRes.Login;
        item.Action = "Login";
        item.RouteInfo = new { controller = "Account", area = ""};
    }
    return PartialView("MenuLinkItem", item);
}
```

ViewModel Class

```
public class MenuLinkItem
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }
        public object RouteInfo { get; set; }
    }
```

PartialView "MenuLinkItem"

```
@model ACTS.UI.Models.MenuLinkItem
@Html.ActionLink(Model.Text, Model.Action, Model.RouteInfo)
```

And then in my View i just called

```
@{Html.RenderAction("AuthenticationLink", new { controller = "Account"}); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `@` symbol before the `Html.ActionLink` HTML helper calls, like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(GlobalRes.BlogEditProfile, "Edit", "Profile");
```

Without the `@` symbol it will not generate the link as part of the output HTML.

So your view should look like this:

```
<div>
 @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
 {
      @Html.ActionLink(GlobalRes.BlogEditProfile, "Edit", "Profile");
 }
 @if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
 {
      @Html.ActionLink(GlobalRes.Login, "Login", "Account");
 }
```

---

Note: The `@` is necessary since you are not defining a Razor code block, the `@` in the `if` is only declaring the conditional block, but it is not automatically output any and all HTML helper calls inside of the conditional block unless you prefix the HTML Helper with the `@` symbol.